# Example 3.84 in Axler: Quotient spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces

Axler defines a quotient space as follows:

> Suppose $U$ is a subspace of $V$. Then the quotient space $V/U$ if the set of all affine subsets of $V$ parallel to $U$. In other words,
> $$V/U = \{v + U : v \in V\}.$$

As an example of one, he gives:

> If $U$ is a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ containing the origin, then $\mathbb{R}^3/U$ is the set of all lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ parallel to $U$.

Geometrically this should be a set of 'vertical lines' covering $\mathbb{R}^3$, but I do not know how to create such a plot nor do I understand where it came from. The best I have been able to do is work it out algebraically.

First, by a "line" in $\mathbb{R}^3$, I assume Axler means a subset of the form
$$U = \{(x,0,0) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$
Then we consider $\mathbb{R}^3/U$. Having fixed a point $(a,b,c)$, its equivalence class is the set of all $(x,y,z)$ satisfying:
\begin{align*}
(a,b,c) \sim (x,y,z) \iff (a - c, b - y, c - z) \in U \iff b - c = 0, c - z = 0 \iff b = c, c = z.
\end{align*}
It made more sense when I picked an explicit point and an explicit line, but the punchline should be that I get a line through $(a,b,c)$ parallel to $U$. But I do not know how to plot this or what "parallel" means in multiple dimensions.

Comment: You have some typos: should be $(a,b,c)\sim(x,y,z)$ iff $(a-x,b-y,c-z)\in U$ iff $b=y$ and $c=z$. Note that the set of points with the same $y$ and $z$ coordinates as $\mathbf v$ are preciselt the set of points that lie on a line through $\mathbf v$ parallel to the $x$-axis.

Comment: In terms of visualisation/creating a plot, perhaps [this image would help](https://img1.yiwugou.com/i004/2016/03/07/24/95e86940d11e7c83da856ab02a80bbe9.jpg@700w.jpg)?

Comment: The image is helpful, and it's what I had in the back of my head, but I'm trying to understand what each of those sticks (pencils?) is. It's certainly an equivalence class and a line, but what's its equation? I don't know how exactly to "plot" such a line in three-dimensional space.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better served with the "point-and-vector" description of a line (note that in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you would need two non-equivalent linear equations to determine a line; in $\mathbb{R}^n$ you would need $n-1$ linearly independent linear equations to determine a line).

A line in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be described by a pair of $n$-tuples, a basepoint $\mathbf{b}_0$ and a "direction" $\mathbf{v}\neq\mathbf{0}$,
$$\mathbf{b}_0 = (a_1,\ldots,a_n),\qquad \mathbf{v}=(v_1,\ldots,v_n).$$
The line consists precisely of all points of the form
$$\mathbf{p} = \mathbf{b}_0 + t\mathbf{v},\quad t\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Geometrically, you are taking the vector $\mathbf{v}$, stretching/contracting/flipping it by a factor of $t$, and then placing its base at $\mathbf{b}_0$. The line consists of all the endpoints you can get this way. Algebraically, it consists of all $n$-tuples of the form
$$(a_1+tv_1, a_2+tv_2,\ldots,a_n+tv_n),\qquad t\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Two lines, $L_1=\mathbf{b}_0+t\mathbf{v}$ and $L_2=\mathbf{c}_0+t\mathbf{w}$ are parallel if and only if the two vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ are parallel, if and only if they are each a scalar multiple of the other.